# Swift / Spritekit: Play music through specific scenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have a game in which I have several tutorial scenes.

I am able to add music to each scene using `AVFoundation`, and an `AVAudioPlayer()`.

What I need to do is be able to start music in a specific scene, and have it continue playing in the background for only related scenes.

For example:

1. Start `tutorialMusic` in Tutorial Menu
2. Continue `tutorialMusic` in Tutorial A
3. Continue `tutorialMusic` in Tutorial B
4. Continue `tutorialMusic` in Tutorial Menu
5. Stop `tutorialMusic` and Play `mainMenuMusic` in the Main Menu

**What I've Tried**

I have tried placing the `AVAudioPlayer()` in the view controller, however I found that propagates to every scene, regardless of what it is. I am also unable to find the view controller's instance of `AVAudioPlayer` to stop it.

I have tried adding the `tutorialMusic` to each Tutorial scene, however that restarts the music every time a user opens a different Tutorial scene, which is sloppy, and if the user is moving quickly, it degrades performance and is really annoying.

**My Question**

Is there a way to extend the Main Tutorial Scene throughout each sub tutorial scene, such that the main instance of `AVAudioPlayer` is accessible and propagates through each tutorial?

Ultimately I want to ensure that in each section (Tutorial Menu Scene, Tutorial A Scene, Tutorial B Scene, etc.) the `tutorialMusic` starts only once and continuously plays until the user exits back to the Main Menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might want to do is use a ***Singleton***. Doing so, you'll be able to have a sound player available from anywhere within your app.

Here is one that might fit your needs : https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils/blob/master/SKTUtils/SKTAudio.swift (Ray Wenderlich).

Used like so : `SKTAudio.sharedInstance().playBackgroundMusic(filename: yourTutorialMusicName)`. Then in your menu you call it again with your other music.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll give it a shot and let you know.